# Combinatoric analysis of groups with 5 distinct elements

Tags: combinatorics

I have $05$ groups of numbers with $05$ numbers each, generating a total of $25$ numbers.

Group 01 $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$

Group 02 $\{6,7,8,9,10\}$

Group 03 ​​$\{11,12,13,14,15\}$

Group 04 $\{16,17,18,19,20\}$

Group 05 $\{21,22,23,24,25\}$

What is the probability of choosing $15$ numbers such that $8$ are even, $7$ are odd, with $4$ being prime numbers?

Among this result, what is the probability that $X$ numbers of a given group are chosen?

In other words, what is the probability of choosing a particular quantity of a given group taking into consideration the total of odd, or even  or prime numbers?

See example:

What is the probability that of $15$ numbers to choose from we choose :

$4$ numbers from Group 1

$4$ numbers from Group 2

$3$ numbers from Group 3

$3$ numbers from Group 4

$1$ number of Group 5

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  Please check to see whether I changed the meaning of your first question.  Also, please [edit] your question to show what you have attempted and explain where you are stuck so that you receive responses that address the specific difficulties you are encountering.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: What have you tried? Did you get stuck? Can you ask a more specific mathematical question about where you got stuck?

Comment: Take a look [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) for suggestions on how to improve your question.

Comment: As you are new to the site:  people here tend to not respond well (or at all) to questions like this that look like homework problems and which show absolutely no effort.  That said, people will meet you half way if you show plausible work.  As a small hint to get you started:  it helps to distinguish two cases, according to whether or not the number $2$ is selected.